# Microsoft Live Connect Api - Authorization Issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, onedrive, live-connect-sdk

I am developing a demo app on Windows Phone 8 using the Microsoft Live Connect Api to access the sky drive.

Below is my code :

In Xaml :

```
<live:SignInButton Name="skyBtn" ClientId="MY_Client_Id" Scopes="wl.basic" Branding="Skydrive"  TextType="Login" Margin="109,403,153,131" SessionChanged="skyBtn_SessionChanged"/>
```

I have used built in button to sign in.

In xaml.cs :

```
private void skyBtn_SessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {
      session = e.Session;
      client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
      tbMessage.Content = "Connected!";
    }
}
```

Basically  my problem is on
 if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected) line

Status always come unknown

I have searched a lot but I'm not able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare internet access for your application.

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" /> as well? It is needed to show the login screen.

Comment: this option is also already checked, there is something else wrong with this code

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code. Use e.Error to get the error message. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/microsoft.live.controls.liveconnectsessionchangedeventargs.error.aspx

Comment: in e.Error This message comes --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthClient.<LoginAsync>d__c.MoveNext()